# how to listen to post requests from foursquare push api

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, foursquare

I have set up everything required for the foursquare push api, including a secure server.
Now my question is what do I need to do to get data from that request and display on my web page. Foursquare API sends a POST to a URL which I can handle with a view.

Do I need to use AJAX calls, or just handle the post request in a view and update something in the database and show data from that database with ajax.. open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

No, all you need to do is send requests and receive responses. Please take a look at this -> [python-requests.org](http://www.python-requests.org) -> The documentation provided how you can send and receive requests.

So, for example, you could send a `POST` request like so:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', <your arguments here>)
```

And now `r` would contain the `POST` response from the said url.

Comment: True, but the request automatically gets created when ever someone checks in to my venue.

Comment: So the flow is --> I own a venue. So, everytime some-one checksin, foursquare generates a POST and sends it to a url for me to handle.

Comment: @AdRoiT: In that case, set up a view that handles this kind of `POST` request.

Comment: okay I got that, what should I do in the view to update the page dynamically. I mean every time I get that POST, how do I make it such that the data I extract from that shows up on my web page.

Comment: @AdRoiT: Now you're talking. You can do it in two ways, you can use your views and still update your data, just change your view to accommodate the new data. Secondly, you might use a task manager, like `celery`. Either way, I'm not going to write your code for you, so you need to understand the foursquare API better, and what kind of data its going to send you and how you can update that data in your database to update your webpage.

Comment: Hey really appreciate your effort. I'm still learning.
Just need to know a bit more. So, I have a page open abc.com/welcome and just now I got a POST on abc.com/handlePOST now how do I update the abc.com/welcome page... I dont need the code, just trying to understand what needs to be done. I'll get json object wich I can parse easily.

Comment: Create a database element, or something like that, that you can save the `POST` data to. After that, simple make a database call and get your `POST` data.